# How to increase the precision when I use double camera stereo algorithm of OpenCV

Tags: opencv, kinect

Now my work is Stereo the Kinect2.0 depth camera and color camera.

My method is use Kinect fusion SDK get the mapping image(depth camera) and color image(color camera).Then use those image as left and right input image of OpenCV Camera Calibration Stereo Algorithm.

These are some example of my input image.
[left0.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKKqU.jpg) [right0.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XyH1.jpg)

Anybody have some way can increase the presicion when I use Stereo of OpenCV. As much precision as possible.
Such as how to set the chessboard.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, try being more precise.

Comment: Thank you for reminding. I already update my question.

Comment: **1.** Is this the Kinect 1 or 2? They are very different sensors. **2.** You're using a depth image and an intensity image in OpenCV's stereo calibration? It expects two intensity images. There are kinect-specific calibration techniques [like this one](http://wiki.ros.org/kinect_calibration/technical).

Comment: (1).It's Kinect2.0 (2) Now I just want get the R and T cameraMatrix between the two images. Because the left image is  mapping image(color2depth) from the Kinect2.0 SDK, the right image is color image of  Kinect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you actually want the transform between the color and infrared cameras. The [left0.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKKqU.jpg) you provided is a composite of the two cameras (you can't use that for calibration).

You could try to use OpenCV's stereo calibration on the color image and the infrared image (don't use the depth at all). But it would be best to use an algorithm designed specifically for calibrating the Kinect v2, [like this one](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2), that uses the depth in the calibration.

Comment: Thank for your help. My boss tell me he just want  the  transform between those two image, I already got some R and T cameraMatrix,but It's not 100% match,the best just 95%. so I want to ask how to increase the presicon.

Comment: An image doesn't exist in 3D space, so it doesn't make sense to look for a 3D transform between images. It does make sense if you're talking about cameras. However, the left0.jpg is a composite image from both the infrared camera (for depth) and the color camera (for intensity). Sure, you can get a transform out of OpenCV's stereo calibration function with these two images, but it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I already got a 3D mesh from Kinect. And mapping the left0.jpg (composite image) on it. We got 8 Angle of view, so we have 8 images like left0.jpg. But you know thouse image coincide at some place. It might has double image. But Thouse left0.jpg doesn't have double image. thouse right0.jpg have some double image that means the transform isn't 100% match. So I ask How to increase the precision.

Comment: If you're talking about 'calibrating' transforms for multiple views, it's not called calibration, it's called 3D reconstruction or Simultaneous Localization and Mapping. OpenCV's stereo calibration does not handle this, and doesn't take advantage of depth information. This is a well-studied field with plenty of algorithms; Kinect Fusion is one example. I think that you should read some of the literature to find out how the algorithm works, and what the difference is between stereo camera and Kinect SLAM.

Comment: Thanks, Just like you said, that's the right way to 3D reconstruction. But it will be much more complicated, and out of my league. Now I just want to increase the presicion. I feel so sorry, but this is my job.